# I would like to use Flutter to display a map-like illustration on a Google Map like the attached image

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I would like to display an illustration that imitates a map on a GoogleMap like this one.
However, I don't know how to implement something like this in Flutter using the `google_map_flutter` package.
If anyone knows how to implement this, please let me know.
[image]

Comment: see [TileOverlay](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/TileOverlay-class.html) - the docs say: "A set of images which are displayed on top of the base map tiles.

These tiles may be transparent, allowing you to add features to existing maps"

Comment: Have you ever used `TileOverlay`?

Comment: no, I have not used it

Comment: I knew it. I understand. Thank you.